# How to insert data using "org.apache.log4j.DBAppender" in log4j appender

Tags: sql, xml, log4j, weblogic, appender

What I want is to insert the log's information into a database using the weblogic database configuration ‘ModuleDs’ that why I use dbAppender. But when I try to test the log4j code the DBAppender class  doesn’t got the query that I wrote and initialize it by a strange one :'INSERT INTO  logging_event_property ... '

Here is my code .xml :

`<appender name="CreerLog" class="org.apache.log4j.DBAppender">
       <connectionSource class="org.apache.log4j.receivers.db.JNDIConnectionSource">
        <param name="jndiLocation" value="moduleDS" />
     </connectionSource>
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="INSERT INTO FICHIERLOG ( ID, DATECREATION,  CONTENUFICHIER) VALUES (BLT_FICHIERLOG_SEQ.nextval, SYSDATE, null)"/>
</appender>`

Comment: You're trying to insert sql via ConversionPattern, which is definitely not allowed. The param `ConversionPattern` refers to the formatting that you want the log message to have

Comment: Also, it appears I was wrong about conversion layout: Both this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444683/log4j-database-appender) and this (http://www.randombugs.com/java/dbappender-log4j-12.html0 may help you. The second shows a use case of DBAppender in a log4j.properties file

Comment: The solution that you propose with jdbcAppender dosent give the possibility of using  server's database config and u have to assign the driver name,password,username,each time u change the environement.